# CloudFormation to setup CodePipeline/CodeBuild to deploy SAM application

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have successfully setup CodePipeline and CodeBuild to deploy my SAM applications. But now I want to convert this to CloudFormation. How do I do this? I followed the steps here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/automating-deployment.html

I am stuck at the CodeBuild part of the CloudFormation template ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're looking for an example of how to set up CodePipeline and CodeBuild using Cloudformation, I'd recommend checking out [this example template](https://github.com/Giftbit/sam-scaffold/blob/master/typescript/infrastructure/ci.yaml) from one of my colleagues, which does all of this.

In the example, you can see [how a code build project](https://github.com/Giftbit/sam-scaffold/blob/master/typescript/infrastructure/ci.yaml#L84) is set up using [AWS::CodeBuild::Project](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-codebuild-project.html), and [how it's refererenced in the CodePipeline Build step](https://github.com/Giftbit/sam-scaffold/blob/master/typescript/infrastructure/ci.yaml#L301) by using a referencing a common ProjectName parameter. Checkout the documentation for [AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-codepipeline-pipeline.html).

Hopefully that helps, but if you need further assistence, I'd try clarifying what you've done so far, and what specifically you're getting stuck on.

Comment: Great stuff there! Thank You!