# How do I identify what IAM permissions are required for AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I want to use CloudFormation. `package` and `deploy` functions but how do I go about determining what IAM permissions are required to run these?

In general, how do I determine what permissions are required?

Comment: read an intro or tutorial then use this reference http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference.html

Comment: What is your CloudFormation Template doing? Are you executing the stack as a CloudFormation service role?

Comment: @JamieStarke, its creating lambda resources etc. Currently I am using a normal user to upload the template. I intend to use CI to do this in the future so if so I will need a service role?

Comment: Did you every figure this out? I have a big template with VPCs, Internet Gateways and ECS, ECR and many other things. Might be really hard to manually figure out what permissions to grant.

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed no, I think from what I understand from the answers and Google, its impossible. I just used relatively broad permissions in the end. Mainly limiting my resources using a project prefix

Comment: May be this helps: https://serverfault.com/a/953263/457325

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there anyway to determine what IAM permissions I actually need for a CloudFormation template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51596254/is-there-anyway-to-determine-what-iam-permissions-i-actually-need-for-a-cloudfor)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the fact that you are using this for Lambda, I'm guessing that this is related to your other question **[CloudFormation to setup CodePipeline/CodeBuild to deploy SAM application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141270/cloudformation-to-setup-codepipeline-codebuild-to-deploy-sam-application)**.

In the answer to that question I referenced an [Example CloudFormation Template](https://github.com/Giftbit/sam-scaffold/blob/master/typescript/infrastructure/ci.yaml). If you look at the [CloudFormationServicePolicy](https://github.com/Giftbit/sam-scaffold/blob/master/typescript/infrastructure/ci.yaml#L187) from that example, you will likely find everything you need.

---

For the answer to this specific question though, there are two parts

To **package** you'll need:

- A Deployment Artifact bucket (`ArtifactBucket`)
- `s3:PutObject` permissions for the user to the `ArtifactBucket`

To **deploy** is much harder to answer. In the above referenced [CloudFormationServicePolicy](https://github.com/Giftbit/sam-scaffold/blob/master/typescript/infrastructure/ci.yaml#L187) you can find a full set of permissions we use with CloudFormation to deploy a function. At the very least, you'll need:

- `iam:PassRole` (assuming you're passing an existing role)
- `lambda:CreateFunction`
- `lambda:UpdateFunctionCode`
- `lambda:UpdateFunctionConfiguration`
- `lambda:AddPermission`
- `lambda:GetEventSourceMapping`
- `lambda:CreateEventSourceMapping`
- `lambda:DeleteEventSourceMapping`

If you're doing your deploy through the console, you'll likely also need:

- `iam:GetRole`
- `iam:ListRole`
- `lambda:GetFunction`
- `lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration`

Comment: Is there an automated way to do this?